# How to skip one JSP file from Apache Weblogic plugin

Tags: apache, weblogic12c

Requirement: 
 How to use both Path based and expression based routing in Apache weblogic plugin ? 
Only the requests from path /website and ending with *.jsp and *.do should be routed to weblogic

We are using Apache 2.4.29 and Weblogic 12.2. 
The current Apache weblogic plugin configuration is

```
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
  WebLogicCluster weblogic1.server.com:8080,weblogic2.server.com:8080,
  MatchExpression *.jsp
  MatchExpression *.do
</IfModule>
```

This is working as expected but we got a request from monitoring team to server one JSP file with only HTML content from the webserver. I am not able to skip this one file (/monitor/test.jsp) from routing to plugin

I tried

```
<Location /weblogic>
  SetHandler weblogic-handler
</Location>
```

and

```
MatchExpression *.jsp
  MatchExpression *.do
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using like this.. works for me

```
<Location ~ "/website.*/.*(?=\.).(jsp|do.*)">
SetHandler weblogic-handler
</Location>
```